# Can GeoEXT 1.0 be used along with ExtJS 4.0?

Tags: geoext, ext-js

On the GeoExt website their tutorial page has some instructions on how to setup up a application to use GeoEXT. [This is the page I am referring to.](http://www.geoext.org/tutorials/quickstart.html#getting-geoext)

It mentions that you should download GeoEXT 1.0 and ExtJS 3.2. I have since noticed that Sencha has released ExtJS 4. Can ExtJS 4 be used along side GeoEXT 1.0 without any issues? Or should I go by the book and install ExtJS 3.2?

Thanks
Ando

Comment: It appears that it is not so seamless. The directory structure and files of ExtJS 4.0 is quite different to that of ExtJS 3.2.

Comment: Nope. Honestly, you can just go the pure jQuery/jQueryUI route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was recently asked on the GeoExt mailing list - http://www.geoext.org/pipermail/dev/2011-May/001008.html

In a word - no, and there are as yet [no ongoing development plans to do so](http://www.geoext.org/pipermail/dev/2011-May/001009.html), but it will be done eventually.

Answer (score 2):

I create new project in github to translate GeoExt 1.1 to Extjs 4
https://github.com/vahid-sohrabloo/GeoExt4

Comment: So vahid writes code to address this issue months later, open sources it and then and he gets downvoted for the short sentence? upvoting.